# Change Attribute Of Membership Provider Programmatically In Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, membership-provider

I have the following defaultmembership provider in my web.config

```
<add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
```

I am trying to update the **enablePasswordReset** from **false** to **true** programmatically but am struggling.. This is as far as I got!

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
var section = (MembershipSection)config.GetSection("system.web/membership");

var defaultProvider = section.DefaultProvider;
var providerSettings = section.Providers[defaultProvider];

// Now what?
```

Now I can't figure out how to get the attribute and update it?  any hints / examples greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out

```
        var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
        var section = (MembershipSection)config.GetSection("system.web/membership");

        var defaultProvider = section.DefaultProvider;
        var providerSettings = section.Providers[defaultProvider];
        providerSettings.Parameters.Set("enablePasswordReset", "true");
        config.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a custom membership provider and using another source for the setting.  It can be dangerous to change a setting; I assume this is a user-exposed feature to allow an admin to turn it on or off?

If you can create a custom membership provider that pulls the information from the database or XML file and then allow the feature or not.  Not sure exactly where to put this code, it would depend on whether you are using the ASP.NET controls, or if you are custom using the API...

HTH.